# Produce a dictionary map from a map in golang

Tags: json, dictionary, go, slice

This is the code that I am trying to make run on playground: http://play.golang.org/p/zX1G50txzf

I have this map:

```
map[producer:Tesla model:Model S year:2015]
```

and I want turn this into this :

```
[map[field:producer value:Tesla] map[field:model value:S] map[field:year value:2015]]
```

but in the end I will get this:

```
[map[field:year value:2015] map[field:year value:2015] map[field:year value:2015]]
```

Looks like every time the loop iterate over the original map, I am copying the reference instead of the value, so I end up with the last value replicated 3 times, instead of one of each.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new `temp` map needs to be created on each iteration of the loop. Otherwise, you are just overwriting the same map:

```
for key, value := range res {
    temp := make(map[string]interface{})
    // ...
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/v-RaL2fswp

Comment: thank you so much, worked like a charm. I tried this approach, making a temp map, but I was creating outside the loop, giving the same results.

Comment: @GilmarPalega: No problem. Remember to [accept answers that solve your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).